# Access to folder is denied (log shipping)

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I am trying to log ship from server A to B. I have done everything to configure log shipping but when I try to run the job at Server B while copying a backup from server A, ikt gives me an error:

> can not access the path (Server A backup folder name) access is denied.

I have shared backup folder at server A with admin account moreover with Everyone. I also tried to change SQL Server agent config and use option (this account) in properties and fill my system account.

Please help me to fix this problem and explain a little like:

1. Is there any problem with sharing the account at server A
2. Do I need to change my SQL Server Agent service account and how?

Let's say at server A there is a folder backup in E drive and there is a folder restore at server B in E drive. I am trying to login to SQL Server through Windows service credential in server A.

Public ip for my two servers is 10.201.4.111 and 10.201.4.112 and my service accounts are `local system`, which are built in accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks all for answers..solved my problem created two user accounts with the same name and same password in each server and then used them in sql agent services under "this account" option

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see the output of the actual job itself.

You mentioned you are using `local system`, if so then you need to grant permissions to the computer account on the folder.  The account you give permissions to would be in the format:

```
<DomainName>\<ServerName>$
```

So for a computer called ServerA on the Contoso domain you would give permissions to the folder for this account

```
Contoso\ServerA$
```

The `$` on the end means this is a computer account.

If this works you may still run into issues with logging  if the computer accounts don't have any permissions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a domain account as your SQL Service account.

Ask your system administrator to supply you with a domain user for your SQL Server services to use.

Make sure that account has sufficient rights on both servers & folders, in particular make sure that the agent accounts on both servers have access (read/write) to the folder(s) you are using for the log shipping.

I tend to use one folder, and use a shared folder. This is for me in most cases the most reliable method.

Answer (score 1):

Copy job failed with the following message:

Error: Access to the path '\WIN-T97MHK9GED1\Primary' is denied.(mscorlib) ***

I changed the user account of SQL Server Agent service to .\Administrator on secondary server only. And it resolved the issue. Please see the screenshot:

[image]